# Lego 42082 Rough Terrain Crane superstructure does not rotate easily when master selector is set to neutral

Tags: technic, gears

My son has been building the Lego 42082 crane and is on bag 9.  I don't believe the central section is functioning properly as I believe the rings should turn much more easily by hand than ours does.

We just watched a video of someone operating this crane and they noted that when the super-structure selector or the master selector are set to neutral the superstructure (main section that sits on the crane base) can be easily rotated by hand.  I have now seen this in other videos: even when the crane is partially built the main circular rings can spin easily.

Right from the time my son completed bag #2 we noticed the center solid black ring could not spin easily by hand.  However if we were to spin the white gear on the bottom of the crane (I only see one white one), it would make the other gears nearby turn and would cause the black circular section on top to slowly spin.  So we figured it was operating properly and that the motor would cause this all to turn. We now see videos showing the black rings should be much easier to turn by hand than ours does.  When I turn it to the left it turns with light force.  If I turn it to the right it requires more force to turn.  But in both cases it is clearly not spinning easily enough.

We are on about bag 9 so I am not sure if the only issue is that it does not turn easily when in neutral, or if this means that this section will not turn at all with the motor.  I am hoping to figure out how serious this issue is before going any further (is it likely to still function with the motor) and if anyone has a suggestion how to fix it so it can turn easily by hand.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I have not built this set myself, however I went through instructions to understand your issue. Based on your description it seems to me that gear train used to rotate the top section is currently stopped/blocked and by applying force you are overcoming white gear's resistance, which is a clutch gear and is a safety feature.

There should be a lever (#3 below) on the other size of the model. Per my understanding it should be in neutral/central/top position to allow top section rotate freely. Any other position would engage gear train with motor and would not spin freely until you overcome resistance of clutch gear.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Alex.  We did have the lever #3 in the correct position and it was still not operating freely.  My son completed the entire build now though and everything works well and even this issue seems to have largely resolved itself.  Thanks again!